# Multiple Instances of a form are unified on submit

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a form, which has to have some fields multiple times. Thats why I extracted all fields, that should appear multiple times, into the class `AdvandcedGame`. All fields that are unique are in the `Form` class. The `Form` class is also the only one with a submit-button. When I press submit, all instances of `AdvancedGame`(A,B,C) are unified(A,A,A). Can you tell me why and how could I fix this?

Here is the code as simplified as possible

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField

class AdvandcedGame(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('name')

class Ui(FlaskForm):
    submit = SubmitField('submit')

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "303"


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def root():
    form = Ui()
    games = [AdvandcedGame(name='A'), AdvandcedGame(name='B'), AdvandcedGame(name='C')]

    for game in games:
        app.logger.info(game.name.data)
    # outputs
    # A
    # B
    # C

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        for game in games:
            app.logger.info(game.name.data)
        # outputs
        # A
        # A
        # A
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, games=games)



# Run the application
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

templates/index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% if form is defined %}
            <form method="POST" action="{{ form.url }}">
                {{ form.csrf_token }}
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{ games[0].name.label }}
                        </td>
                        {% for game in games %}
                            <td>
                                {{ game.name }}
                            </td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=3>
                            {{ form.submit}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at WTForms FieldList (https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.FieldList). The forms do not work as you assume, that is why what you try does not work. The name of the field is the key to the data, so your three fields are collapsed into one.

Comment: @MennoHölscher Thanks for your explanation and your hint. With the FieldList it's now working as expected.